# Dictionary of fields in wtforms

Tags: python, dictionary, field, wtforms

I'd like to know if it's possible to create a dictionary of fields within a form, using wtforms.

The reason is that I have a dictionary of locations, which I render into a table using jinja. Before I was using wtforms, I could easily handle the inputs for each of these:

```
{% for locKey, loc in locDict.iteritems() %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ loc['name'] }}</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="{{ locKey }}" name="locKey"></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %
```

However, on moving to wtforms, I can't figure out how to do this tidily. I have tried to create a dictionary of fields within the wtform, but it appears this is not being instantiated, as I get `<UnboundField(IntegerField ...)>` rendered in my forms. You can see what I mean with the following example.

```
from wtforms.validators import NumberRange
from wtforms import Form, IntegerField

# dictionary of locations with certain attributes
locDict = {}
locDict['locOne'] = {'name': 'Location One', 'popn': 1000}
locDict['locTwo'] = {'name': 'Location Two', 'popn': 2000}
locDict['locThree'] = {'name': 'Location Three', 'popn': 3000}

class testForm(Form):
    # standard field
    normalField = IntegerField('Normal Field', validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=100)])

    # initiate dictionary of fields
    locFields = {}
    for locKey, loc in locDict.iteritems():
        locFields[locKey] = IntegerField(loc['name'], validators=[NumberRange(min=0, max=loc['popn'])])

# test the form
testFormInstance = testForm()
print testFormInstance.normalField
print testFormInstance.locFields['locOne']
print testFormInstance.locFields['locTwo']
print testFormInstance.locFields['locThree']

# returns:
#<input id="normalField" name="normalField" type="text" value="">
#<UnboundField(IntegerField, ('Location One',), {'validators': [<wtforms.validators.NumberRange object at 0x7f8367970050>]})>
#<UnboundField(IntegerField, ('Location Two',), {'validators': [<wtforms.validators.NumberRange object at 0x7f8367963f90>]})>
#<UnboundField(IntegerField, ('Location Three',), {'validators': [<wtforms.validators.NumberRange object at 0x7f83679700d0>]})>
```

I've spent hours on this (including perusing stackoverflow and the wtforms documentation), but to little avail. My hope is that someone knows how I can get each element of the dictonary to be instantiated, and hence voila!

Other solutions I can think of:

1. It appears possible to do something with FieldList. However, even if it's possible, I don't think I could use this in the way I do above for creating my table, i.e. looping through the distinct locations.
2. Creating all the forms individually using the `exec` function in python, e.g. `exec("loc%s = IntegerField ....") % locKey`. This worked, except then I couldn't render it with jinja, as I'd have to be doing something like this, which didn't work:

   ```
   {% for locKey, loc in locDict.iteritems() %}
   <tr>
       <td>{{ loc['name'] }}</td>
       <td>{{ form.loc{{ locKey }} }}</td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
   ```
3. Take the approach of 2, and then create an ugly manual script to create the html template (i.e. so that the html template explicitly has `{{ form.loclocOne }}` etc. This is rather ugly, but the only feasible solution I can see thus far.

**Note**: as you can see in the above example, I need to see differing maximums in each field.